# How to add an element to 'body' using Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have created an element like this:

```
var myDiv = new Element('div');
myDiv.update('Hello!');
```

I want to add `myDiv` to body.

I tried

```
$('body').insert(myDiv);
```

But it is not working. I also tried

```
$('body')[0].insert(myDiv);
```

thinking that `$('body')` was returning an array. Even that didn't work.

How can I add `myDiv` to body?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$ is a shorthand for document.getElementById(), $$ is the more versatile prototype function. To access the (first) body element in your document, use:

```
$$('body')[0].insert(myDiv);
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Since the documentation said `$$(cssRule...) -> [HTMLElement...]`, I thought I could only give css class names when using $$ and not tag names! I feel stupid :D

Comment: `$$('body')[0]` "works", but is inefficient and unnecessary. Instead, use `$(document.body)` as Pekka suggested.

Comment: to make this complete: `$(document.body).insert(myStuff);` is the way to go

Answer (score 15):

How about

```
$(document.body).insert(myDiv);
```

?

Differently from jQuery, in Prototype, `$('body')` fetches the element with the **id** `body`.

Comment: Hi, $(body).insert(myDiv) doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Senthil apologies - it should have been `document.body`. Anyway, `$$` seems to work fine so I assume it's sorted.

Answer (score 1):

$$('body')[0] works fine

Answer (score 1):

As Pekka said, you first need to extend document.body with Prototype's DOM extensions to be able to use Prototype's insert() method. 
Although Firefox seems to somehow be able to execute the insert() anyway :)

for more information: http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/extensions