# How to check (if statement) body element class value in Prototype JS library?

Tags: prototypejs

```
How to check body element (<body></body>) in prototype?
```

This is not working:

```
        if( $('body').hasClassName("catalog-product-view") ){
          alert("yes");
       }

        if(!$('body').hasClassName("catalog-product-view") ){
          alert("no");
       }
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is looking for an element with an `id` of `'body'`. Try giving the `<body>` an id and referencing that.

Edit: or, looking at [How to add an element to 'body' using Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801304/how-to-add-an-element-to-body-using-prototype), use `$$('body')[0]`

Comment: hasClassName is for class not id or?

Comment: I am not able to add id to body tag, is there any way to call body tag using prototype?

Comment: E.g. in jQuery I can load body or  #body_id or .body_class. How to do something like this in prototype?

Comment: did a quick search and found a similar answer - edited my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

to catch the body element do :

```
$(document.body)
```

this will return the body element !

to check the class use :

```
$(document.body).hasClassName("catalog-product-view")
```

and finally you can do what you need with :

```
$(document.body).hasClassName("catalog-product-view") ? alert("yes") : alert("no");
```